# "updatedb; locate foo" vs "ls -laR > somefile; grep foo somefile"

Tags: grep

On a single-user system where security isn't an issue, is there any
advantage to using "updatedb" and "locate" (or slocate or mlocate) 
instead of just doing "ls -laR > somefile" nightly and then using 
"grep phrase somefile" to find files?

In fact, it would seem that grep is more flexible than locate since it 
allows for regular expressions.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific scenario, the differences are marginal, but the `locate` database is optimized for fast searches.

On a multiuser system, modern `locate` replacements have various additional security features so as to e.g. not reveal to another user what files you have in your private directories.

Comment: `locate` is also shorter to type, unless you use a really short filename instead of `somefile` (-:

Comment: Are you saying "locate" is faster than grep because of this optimization? Would that be the advantage?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying.

Comment: But how? Some sort of fulltext indexing? I didn't think locate was that sophisticated. In fact, mlocate.db just looks like a list of my file names separated with nulls.

Comment: It's [a bit more complex than that](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mlocate.db+5). GNU `locate` used to use something called `frecode` but it seems they have changed that part. I would have expected some sort of search-optimized database (B+ tree?) but maybe it's overkill for this application on modern file systems?

Comment: I admit I was oversimplifying. My point: mlocate.db does not seem optimized for fulltext searching. Do you have a canonical URL/source for frecode? Googling yields very little. Maybe frecode itself is the magic I need.